# Markov's inequality proof check

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

Can anyone please check my proof?

We are asked to show that if $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}_+$ is a measurable function then 
$$\int f \ge a \times m(\{f>a\}).$$

I note that $$\int f = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} m(\{f>t\}) dt \ge \int_{[0,a]} m(\{f>t\}) dt \ge \int_{[0,a]} m(\{f>a\}dt= a \times m(\{f>a\})$$

My first inequality is due to the fact that we have non-negative measure and the second one uses the fact that $\{f>a\} \subset \{f>t\}$ for $t \in [0,a]$ hence $m(\{f>t\}) \ge m(\{f>a\})$.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @JohnMath If anyone could please verify my proof. Thank you and sorry for not stating it clearly. Will edit.

Comment: I think it is true.
Nicer way to show it: use $f \geq a\mathbb{1}_{\{f\geq a\}}$ and integrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Markov's inequality and is widely used in Probability Theory. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#In_the_language_of_measure_theory) for a proof.